# how to connect to vm

Tags: virtual-machine, qtp

I have my application(AUT) on a VM and the QTP is installed my local machine with Seat license. When I try to record QTP is not recognising anything in VM, including login. How to solve this problem and whats the script to connect to VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to connect to an application running on a VM with QTP running on the local machine. In order to make this work, install QTP on the VM and run it purely inside the virtual machine.

Comment: Adding on to @AutomatedChaos answer, QTP (and other automation tools) only recognize resources local to the windows desktop on which it is running. So QTP could see the VM window, but the viewer would just be a single object as far as QTP is concerned. Likewise, if you were running QTP locally, and were trying to automate through VNC/RDP, you would see the same kind of behavior.